# dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold is not wokring in vs2019

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, dbcontext

In my ASP.NET Core (V 3.1) WebAPI project, I've the following Nuget packages

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 5.0.4
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer 5.0.4
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools 5.0.4
```

I'm trying to create models as follows-

```
dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=SafeSave;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -o Models
```

But the above command does not create any thing.
What did I miss here?

Comment: Hi @s.k.paul, any updates about this case?

Comment: @FeiHan, I failed to do that from VS2019. Then I did that from VSCode.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you can try to use the following command to install the latest `dotnet ef` as a global tool.

```
dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef
```

And please ensure you install this package `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design` that is required for the Entity Framework Core Tools to work.

Then clear and rebuild your project, and re-run and retry your command to create models.

```
dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=SafeSave;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -o Models
```